# On which sites can I sell fonts I've created?

Tags: fonts, typography

I made a typeface that I would like to sell non-exclusively on several online stores. I have been searching and found a few nice outlets so far.

What are the font shops you know of? Where do you sell your typefaces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been selling my own fonts on [MyFonts](http://www.myfonts.com), [fonts.com](http://www.fonts.com), and [FontShop](http://www.fontshop.com). Almost any font store will accept whatever you want to sell, without any preference except FontShop - they approve your fonts prior to publication and won't be selling a typeface they don't like.

None of these store require exclusive rights, however you will be required by the contract to set the same price for your fonts in any store you are present in (temporary promotional discounts remain up to your liking).

Among the three mentioned stores I've experienced the most revenue from MyFonts, since they have the largest audience, and most foundry promotion was from FontShop (if you are going to continue making and selling your fonts you may care about this).

Comment: I've been selling through MyFonts for over two years and they just refused two fonts I created for the first time.
It seems that from now on, the MyFonts review team will only approve of fonts containing all of the following characters:

abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
1234567890ao123%‰€$¢£¥ áâàäåãæçéêèëíîìïıñóôòöõøœšßúûùüýÿž
ÁÂÀÄÅÃÆÇÉÊÈËÍÎÌÏ ÑÓÔÒÖÕØŒŠ ÚÛÙÜÝŸ .,:;-–—•·...“‘’‘‚“”„‹›«»/\?!¿¡()[]{}
†*&©®@#§+×=_°|

Answer (score 4):

I've not ever sold a typeface, but I know from shopping for them that www.myfonts.com is probably the biggest place to do so. More info [here](http://www.myfonts.com/info/prospectus/). They're not necessarily exclusive:

> Foundries set the retail prices of their fonts. The only limitation is that the pricing must not exceed the regular pricing sold through other channels. A foundry may optionally designate some of its fonts to be available free of charge provided those fonts are exclusive to MyFonts.

[FontShop](http://www.fontshop.com/contact_us.php) will pick up smaller type foundries as well; not sure about that process but their contact page has an option to select about new font submissions. [Veer](http://www.veer.com) came to mind but I was unable to find anything; same with [FontSpring](http://www.fontspring.com).

I don't think the process to sell fonts is as streamlined as the process to sell stock photos; try e-mailing foundries and see what you come up with! Keep us posted :D

Answer (score 2):

Other sources:

- [Creative Market](https://creativemarket.com/)
- [CreateBright](https://createbright.com/) (as of 2021, the link is broken)
- [HypeForType](http://www.hypefortype.com/)
- [MyFonts](http://www.myfonts.com/)